# More efficient data for grid-like game map in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, vuejs2

[image: screenshot of random map with a couple of 'monsters']

I am working on a roguelike game written in Vue.js.

I've started by creating a randomly generated grid-like map (a recursively splitting binary tree), so my data model for the map has just been a 2d array of objects.

Then the view just has nested divs with data attributes ( data-occupied-by="empty" ) and related CSS to style based on that.

```
<div class="row" v-for="row in map">
    <div class="cell" v-for="cell in row">
       <div class="cell-contents" :data-occupied="cell.occupied"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's worked fine for the map, but now I'm adding other objects to spaces.

The problem is that:

```
this.map[ x ][ y ] = { occupant: "monster" };   //for simplicity's sake
```

doesn't trigger a redraw of anything, and manually triggering one of the whole map is slow, which leads me to think I'm barking up the wrong tree with how I'm storing the game data.

Does this model make sense, or should I rethink things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found that using the built-in array ( "push" to build each row of the 2d array, and "splice" to delete/add a cell (i.e. to replace it) allows Vue to track it without having to redraw the entire 2d map.